# Button Overflow™ on bottom sign-up banner at some browser widths

Tags: bug, design, sign-up, banner

The bottom banner asking you to sign up is responsive, but at some widths the leftmost sign-up button and the close button are only partially visible:

[image]

(Safari 15.5 on macOS 12.4)